# How do I solve this CodeIgniter's 'Too few arguments to function' error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day,everyone!
Please, am new to CodeIgniter... Actually,am try to write a search module script using inner join, but I don't know what am not getting right.

This is the error message:
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Career_model::quick_search(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\application\controllers\Pages.php on line 69 and exactly 4 expected

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\application\models\Career_model.php

Line Number: 124

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\application\controllers\Pages.php
Line: 69
Function: quick_search

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\index.php
Line: 286
Function: require_once

This is my controller:

```
function quick()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('username')):
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('username');

        $query = $this->db->query("select * from account where email='$session_data'");
        $data = $query->result();

        foreach ($data as $key => $value);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender','Gender', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('from','lowest age', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('to','highest age', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE):
            $this->load->view('pages/search_result');
        else:
            $gender = $this->input->get_post('gender');
            $from = $this->input->get_post('from');
            $to = $this->input->get_post('to');
            $country = $value->country;

                //I suppose this is where the problem is coming from

            if($this->Career_model->quick_search($gender,$from,$to,$country)):
                $data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','something went wrong...');

                redirect('pages/search_result',$data);
            else:
                $result['data'] = $this->Career_model->quick_search();
                redirect('pages/search_result',$result);
            endif;
        endif;
    endif;
}
```

And here is the Model:

```
function quick_search($gender,$from,$to,$country)
    {

        $this->db->join("about" , "account.ref_id = about.user_id");
        $this->db->where('gender',$gender);
        $this->db->where('country',$country);
        $this->db->where('age',$from);
        $this->db->where('age <=',$to);
        $query = $this->db->get('account');

        return $query->result();

    }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: the error is because you're not providing any arguments when you call your model in else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're not providing any parameters when you call your model in else condition(which expects 4 parameters). I've written a possible solution for you, see if it helps.  
Remove this code to the one below --

```
// Remove this code
if($this->Career_model->quick_search($gender,$from,$to,$country)):
    $data = $this->session->set_flashdata('error','something went wrong...');
    redirect('pages/search_result',$data);
else:
    $result['data'] = $this->Career_model->quick_search(); // this line is causing error because 0 parameters are passed.
    redirect('pages/search_result',$result);
endif;
```

to

```
// This is probably what you want ↓↓ 
   $result = $this->Career_model->quick_search($gender, $from, $to, $country); // get the data once and then check if data empty or not

if(!empty($result)){ // success

    $data['result'] = $result;

}else{  // fail

    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','No data found');
}
redirect('pages/search_result',$data);
```

Comment: Okay... Thanks a lot! At least I can now see the search_result page.

Comment: Please accept as an answer, if it helped you. Happy coding! :)

Comment: I'm trying to extract the content of $data['result'] = $result; using a foreach(){} loop and got hooked. In my search_result.php page, this is what I have foreach ($data as $key => $value):
          echo $value->age;
         endforeach;

Comment: When you send an `array` to the `view`, you use its `keys` to get the value. So use `foreach ($result as $key => $value): echo $value->age; endforeach;`

Comment: Yeah, I've done that severally and I keep getting this A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: pages/search_result.php

Line Number: 23

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\application\views\pages\search_result.php
Line: 23
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\application\controllers\Pages.php
Line: 27
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\hue\index.php
Line: 286
Function: require_once

Comment: the error must be arising when `$result` is empty ie no search result found. so, you'll have to check first `if(isset($result)){foreach(){...}}else{echo 'No result found';}`

Comment: Yeah, I've done that already... Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your efforts...

Comment: Happy to help. :)